# how to limit a vpn software (spotflux) to certain programs and browsers?

Tags: windows-8, vpn, socks-proxy, socks5

I use windows 8 , spotflux vpn to use sites that are blocked by isp.

What I need is to use spotflux only with my browsers - chrome and others, I don't want it to be for all my internet access, because when spotflux is running and connected. All my internet traffic idm, p2p software , and online games. Have to go through spotflux vpn, which is slow sometimes and limited and I only need it for browsing.

How can I use it only for browsing and keep the other softwares going normally by my normal fast connection ?

I used tor project which was amazing and totally what I needed nothing uses it unless I use a socks5 local IP with a specified port until some sites blocked me from using it.

Information might help: spotflux is free, it's similar to hotspot shield I use win8, bitcomet p2p , idm as a downloader , skype , that's all.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is AFAIK to run your VPN and the programs you want to tunnel inside a VM. While it has a little overhead, it is an easy-to-setup way and you have the 100% guarantee that only those programs inside the VM are tunneled, since the VM uses a completely separate network connection from it's host. Just download one of the following freewares:

Oracle VirtualBox

VMWare Player

Windows Virtual PC

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have experience with VM, it's actually a good idea that i didn't think of,  but still, there must be some kinda twisted method or a software, from my many search results, i found something called "tun2socks - badvpn", IDK if it's gonna do the job, it's still in developing and it's an open source so it's hard to use.

Comment: To me that tun2socks thing doesn't sound like what you want. It sounds like some "Tunnel everything through a socks"-Software. I only read the short introduction on Google Code though. Besides, do you have any reason not to use the VM-method?